# Thread dump from a non responding play server

Tags: scala, playframework, threadpool, bonecp

It has been observed that this play app stops responding to new requests after a while. trying to analyze this thread dump. I have uploaded it on a gist [here](https://gist.github.com/birjupat/9366180). do you think BoneCP is causing this behavior looking at the thread dump?